# SCP doesn't transfer files when using multifile bracket expansion

Tags: linux, scp

I'm attempting to use the scp command:

```
scp user@remotehost:/dir/to/\{file1,file2\} .
```

But when I run this, it prompts for password and then ends without transferring the files. If I run following command: (removing the backslashes - keeping same user, host and file names):

```
scp user@remotehost:/dir/to/{file1,file2} .
```

then it runs okay. By okay, I mean that it prompts once for each file but it does transfer the files.

I have also tried to rename my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` just in case it was something in these profiles that were causing problems. This was after trying to use the interactive shell test

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return
```

that seem to cause some problems.

I'm running the **scp** command from my **OpenSuse 42.1** workstation. But I've also tried from a **Redhat 6.3** system. I do not have terminal access to the system I'm trying to get files from.

If I run the command (with slashes - so that it only prompts once) against a different machine from my same workstation then it works as expected.

--- edit 1 ---
Using the -vvv option against the problematic system shows the following version info:

```
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD
debug1: no match: SSHD
```

Using the `-vvv` option against the system that works shows the following:

```
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
```

I see an obvious difference in remote software version. But, is SSHD a real version or is the version possibly being masked/hidden?

--- edit 2 ---
I found these two links that describe the result of no match and it operating in a mode compatible with SSH protocol version 2 specification. I'm just not sure what doc to look for or keyword to use (glob?):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123091/understand-debug-messages-from-sshd

http://www.openssh.com/specs.html

Ideas?

Comment: Just a side note: Exit code 0 typically indicates that everything went smoothly. I know this is not what your question is about but it's good to know that anything *other* than exit code 0 indicates a problem (on *nix systems at least)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I found strange. This wasn't me echo'ing $?. It was the exit code while using scp -v. So scp thinks it worked fine. Though maybe not a good choice to use in a title describing problem (or not - hey, my command is working! :D).

Comment: Can/Should I change the title? I don't see the title as being something I can change. And if i can/should then I'm not sure what a better description might be.

Comment: I think you can change the title by the clicking the "edit" button below your question. The same goes for all other questions. Whether or not you want to is, of course, entirely up to you. But maybe it would make more sense to mention that "SCP doesn't transfer files yet returns 0" or that "SCP doesn't transfer files if there's a backslash in the path" if that's the actual problem

Comment: I just tried `\{file1,file2\}`, `{file1,file2}`, and `'{file1,file2}'`, and all three worked for me (copying two files).  So there may be a configuration or versioning issue here.

Comment: See my edited answer. Probably users shell is to blame, or the `ssh` implementation on the first machine

Answer (score 2):

```
scp user@remotehost:/dir/to/\{file1,file2\} .
```

Works only if the remote side evaluates the remote command in the shell capable of brace expansion. The client sends:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /dir/to/\{file1,file2\}
```

which is in `openssh` [passed as an argument](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c#L1906) to user's default shell, which makes it working even without glob in `scp` code.

The reason why to does not work on some systems might be different `shell` or different `ssh` implementation that might not pass the arguments over the users `shell`.

But you might use `sftp`, such as:

```
sftp -b <(echo get /dir/to/{file1,file2} ) user@remotehost
```

This will run `sftp` in batch mode, do the brace expansion on your client and gets you all the files you are interested in.

Comment: I'm having different trouble (i think password related) when using sftp -b ... And I actually have something that sort of works using sftp but the transfers were not sending the full file. It seemed to only transfer a portion of it which is why I went with attempting to use scp. I understand the difference between bracket expansion on client vs server. But what you're saying sounds like scp doesn't support expansion at all which isn't true since it works against other remote systems. If I am misinterpreting or not understanding something then I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: The second command does expansion on client so you don't need the expansion on server. The standard `scp` from `openssh` does not support glob. You can `grep glob scp.c`, but it does not return any results.
Using passwordless authentication would be preffered for `sftp` in batch mode.

Comment: So you're thinking that the server/remote side may be using the standard scp from openssh that doesn't support glob? Do you know of anyway to verify this (maybe through scp debug)?

Comment: adding `-vvv` switches will tell you versions of both server and client.

Comment: Post the both verbose logs into the edited question. It will help you to understand what is going on there and what commands are issued and run on the remote sides.

Comment: @SteveSummit Ok. My bad. You are right. Just tested and it works. But the brace expansion is evaluated in the remote bash and not in scp itself.

Comment: @Jakuje Right.  (Deleting my earlier comment now that you've updated your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

```
scp user@remotehost:/dir/to/'{file1,file2}' .
```

The glob and bracket expression must be enclosed in single quotes to be interpreted by the remote server **assuming** your shell there is bash-like.

If that doesn't work, try rsync (tm)